# Convert light socket to plug socket for LED lighting strip

Tags: electrical, lighting, led, the-netherlands

I have a european (Netherlands) light socket in my house that I would like to convert to a plug socket to accommodate an [LED lighting strip](http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/catalog/products/90192071/). My builder says it won't work, but he's Polish, I'm English and we talk to each other in Dutch, so I think it might just be a communication problem. Some advice please?

Comment: Can you post an image of the socket?

Answer (score 1):

In the US you could buy a "[Medium Base Polarized Socket Outlet Adapter](https://www.google.com/search?q=Medium%20Base%20Polarized%20Socket%20Outlet%20Adapter)" at any hardware store for a couple bucks.

I suppose both ends are different where you are, but perhaps the picture will be enough to convey the idea?

[image: Medium Base Polarized Socket Outlet Adapter]

Comment: I guess there are no smarts in this component beyond simply converting the connections - so replacing the light socket entirely should be ok too?

Comment: There are definitely no smarts to it -- nothing like a power transformer or microchip or anything.  It's just a physical adaptor.  I don't see why you couldn't do as you intend. I'm not an electrician tho.

Comment: The potential problem with replacing the light socket with an outlet is that there may not be a ground wire running to it. In many locales, it is illegal to install new, ungrounded electrical outlets. If there is a ground, then there's no problem replacing it.

Comment: The ground at the lamp fixture isn't brought to the bulb socket and isn't available to this adapter. You could kluge something by using a grounded-to-ungrounded adapter and running a wire from its ground lug to the fixture... but realistically, I just wouldn't plug anything into it that needed grounding. Double-insulation is an adequate alternative.